# Show header filter in tabulator programmatically

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I'm using Tabulator with Ajax request with remote pagination. When you use Header Filter you only filter data on that page. What I want to do is to show Header Filter when my answer only has 1 page, if it has more than 1 page user could be confused that he is filtering all data rather than just that page.

Is there a method to set `HeaderFilter=true` or false programmatically?

```js
this.tabulator = new Tabulator(this.$refs.table, {
    index: "ANRID",
    data: this.tableData, //link data to table
    locale: true,
    height:"400px",
    responsiveLayout:"collapse",
    pagination:"remote",
    tooltips: true,
    ajaxURL: "/anrs",
    responsiveLayoutCollapseStartOpen:false,
    columns: [
        {title:"+", formatter:"responsiveCollapse", headerSort:false},
        {title:"", formatter:editIcon, width:25, align:"center", headerSort:false},
        {title: "ID", field:"ANRID", headerFilter: false},
        {title:"Fideicomiso", field:"fideicomiso.FondosNombre", width: 150, headerFilter: false},
        {title:"Actividad", field:"actividad", headerFilter: false},
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to update the column definition for the affected column, this can either be done on the table using the ***updateColumnDefinition*** function and specifying the field of the column:

```js
table.updateColumnDefinition("name", {headerFilter:false})
```

or if you have the column component you can call the ***updateDefinition*** function on the column

```js
column.updateDefinition({headerFilter:false})
```

More information on this and other column definition information can be found in the [Column Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.5/columns#replace)